# Finding way out of starting location?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

I'm rather new to adventure mode but since the latest patch I think it is worth taking a closer look into it. So I started as a dwarf two times but I cannot seem to find a way out to the surface. I think I have `[Q]` locations of surface creatures but they seem inaccessible.

Is there a way to easily escape these labyrinths where I was born?

Comment: You may not be able to get out to the surface, but you may be able to escape to the dwarven roads. Or, you may be stuck in a sealed fortress.

Comment: @d.Wats In my latest walk through I found the underground roads but this does not really help, it just makes it even more complicated to find the surface.

Answer (score 2):

While it doesn't yet seem to be easy to determine *how* to get out, simply walking around looking for the up stairs `<` did the trick for me in about a minute.

Comment: I have seen two video's of people picking a dwarf and indeed they start out in a single chamber underground. I however am stuck in a endless network of walls and doors and i try every up stairs i bump into.

Comment: If you're using a version before .40.03 there is a bug in which you can spawn as a Dwarf in an enclosed fortress.

Comment: In my current run i reached the underground road but I have been walking there for ages without quests since i cannot find the surface.

Comment: There should be tracks visible when you press K that are not your own. These should lead you in the right direction. If you cannot find your way, if you walk in one direction you *will* eventually find a fortress, or a trade depot. You have to remember that it's huge and straight for the protection of traders.

Comment: Well, essentially straight :P

Answer (score 1):

**If you're lucky**

I played a few games recently(40.13). Consider this illustration clockwise from top left:

[image]

I spawned and found an *upward staircase*(1). After some exploring, I found rooms with dwarves and stockpiles(2) and those *up/down ramps* side by side nearby. And 30 some floors up there was the exit to the wilderness(3).

**Otherwise, ask for help?**

Another game was less successful as I didn't see any ramps around(but it was still pretty easy to find rooms with dwarves one level up from my starting position). Ask for directions maybe?

[image]

Forget that, I couldn't find something like "ask for a way out of here!" in the 9 pages of things you can ask for. After finding a seven tiles wide passage that engulfed into some underground farms that spanned dozens of screens wide, sometimes going up or down a few, I wandered into an adjacent cave and never made it back...

---

So I suggest you re-embark if you can't find the ramps close to the rooms where the dwarves gather.

Comment: Thanks, but still not the answer i was looking for, although maybe the best until this gets fixed. Well this does get fixed soon i hope because the latest update did a ton to adventure mode.

Comment: @MennoGouw As do I... I don't have more than a few hours experience with adventure mode. I hadn't checked the [bugtrack](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/mantisbt/view.php?id=6541). Most likely some ppl have the bug whereas in other cases the exit is just hard to find. I think you should spawn in the room on the surface. I can see the NPC talk menu has been completely overhauled which adds lots of depth to interactions. But issues need to be ironed out - I stick to pocket worlds as I find generation/loading too long for anything else.